Using ros2 launch to run Python nodes on Windows
I'm running into a problem when I try to use ros2 launch (under Jazzy on Windows 10) to run Python nodes.
The Windows shell doesn't understand shebangs, so it isn't able to determine that it should run Python scripts using Python.  The shell does understand file extensions, though, so I've renamed any Python scripts that don't end in .py to end in .py.
To start, I'm trying to get rosbridge running, and I've been focusing on the rosapi_node.  I renamed it to rosapi_node.py inside the colcon_ws/install/rosapi/lib/rosapi directory.
I've managed to run the newly-renamed rosapy_node.py in two ways:
I can run it directly from the Windows command prompt by calling it (which shows that the Python launcher is correctly configured, I think).
I can also run it with ros2 run rosapi rosapi_node.py
However, I can't run it from inside a launch file: I get this traceback:
c:\Users\robot\colcon_ws\install\rosbridge_server\Lib\rosbridge_server>ros2 launch rosbridge_server test_launch.py
c:\dev\ros2_jazzy\Lib\site-packages\launch\logging\__init__.py:149: UserWarning: Cannot create a symlink to latest log directory: [WinError 1314] A required privilege is not held by the client: 'C:\\Users\\robot\\.ros\\log\\2024-07-16-11-20-42-799604-DESKTOP-T0DU81J-7344' -> 'C:\\Users\\robot\\.ros\\log\\latest'

  warnings.warn(
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\robot\.ros\log\2024-07-16-11-20-42-799604-DESKTOP-T0DU81J-7344
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [rosapi_node.py-1]: exception occurred while executing process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\ros2_jazzy\Lib\site-packages\launch\actions\execute_local.py", line 569, in __execute_process
    transport, self._subprocess_protocol = await async_execute_process(
  File "c:\dev\ros2_jazzy\Lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 139, in async_execute_process
    transport, protocol = await _async_execute_process_nopty(
  File "c:\dev\ros2_jazzy\Lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 45, in _async_execute_process_nopty
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
    transp = _WindowsSubprocessTransport(self, protocol, args, shell,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
    self._start(args=args, shell=shell, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
    self._proc = windows_utils.Popen(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
    super().__init__(args, stdin=stdin_rfd, stdout=stdout_wfd,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I've tried both Python and XML launch files:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='rosapi',
            namespace='turtlesim1',
            executable='rosapi_node.py',
            name='rosapi'
        ),
    ])

<launch>
  <node name="rosapi" pkg="rosapi" exec="rosapi_node.py">
  </node>
</launch>

The ros2 launch documentation is a little sparse, and the code uses enough layers of abstraction that it's difficult to track down.  From what I can see, it looks like the issue is that ros2 launch is passing the Python script to Subprocess as an executable, but Python scripts aren't executable on Windows.
That said, I can't imagine that I'm the first person to try to run Python nodes on Windows... any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I think I figured this out.  The short version: if you have a Python package that uses ament_cmake_python or ament_cmake, it won't work on Windows.  You have to convert the package to use ament_python.
The ament_python build component will generate a .exe file for the python scripts listed in the entry_points['console_scripts'] of the setup.py script.  (Or, perhaps more accurately, setuptools does this this, but ament_python calls setuptools so that it happens.)
It seems that ament_cmake_python and ament_cmake don't have an obvious way to do this, so they don't generate anything that Windows can execute.
This ticket pointed me in the right direction:
https://github.com/ros2/demos/issues/374
